# MS SQL server 2008 - use CSV in query but not import/insert

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a CSV file while I would like to use in a query in junction with existing tables. I would like to be able to use the CSV data in joins and selects, but not have to put it into a permanent table. The reason being my user privileges do not permit me to add tables or write functions.

Is there a work around for me here or am I looking down a dead end road

Comment: "*but not have to put it into a permanent table*", ok, but why don't put that data into **temporary** table and use that table in your queries?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev  thanks for pointing out the tags - I fixed it. I am using SQL server...  I will look into temporary tables. Is it possible to create a temporary table from CSV?

Comment: Usually you don't need to create temporary table "from something". You just creating it like `create table dbo.#YourTableName (columns_definitions)` - in other words like permanent table but having name starting with `#` symbol. Then you can insert into it, and do whatever you want. Table will remain while your connection is open, and will be deleted on connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but I would assume you can do this by using openrowset with something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'c:\test\values.txt', 
  FORMATFILE = 'c:\test\values.fmt') AS a;
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: I should probably mention that if the file is big or you do this often with the same file, you of course should actually load it into the database